# convertPoint: toView: analog in Quartz Core

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit, quartz-core

Is there a function to convert the coordinates of the framework Quartz Core like:

```
convertPoint: toView:
```

becouse if I transform my objects by methods QC convertPoint not working.

Comment: Transformations may invalid .frame and frame.origin or view.center etc. In principle convertPoint should work but when the frame was transformed it has undefined contents.

Comment: if I use myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation, method convertPoint work, but if I rotate my view CABasicAnimation *rotate, convert point returns cover those coordinates that were rotation, I think is conflict frameworks

Comment: What if you use `CGPointApplyAffineTransform(p,t)` to transform the points as well?